# Time series binary classfication

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, random-forest, supervised-learning

**Problem:**

Hi, I m a new machine learning practitioner. I have a dataset about hedge fund. It contains monthly hedge fund returns and some financial metrics. I calculated metrics for every month from 2010 to 2019 December. (2889 monthly data) I want to binary classification and predict hedge funds' class  basis on these metrics for next month. I want make prediction for T+1 from T time. And i want use random forest and other classifiers(Decision Tree,KNN,SVM,logistics regression). I know this dataset is time series problem, how do i convert this to machine learning problem.

I am open to your suggestions and advisories as to what method or approach should be followed in modeling, feature engineering and editing this data set.

Additional Questions:

1)How do I make a data split when using this data for training and test ? 0,80-0,20?. Is there any other method of validation you can recommend?

2)some funds are added to the data later, so not all funds have data of equal length, for example, the "AEB" fund established in 2015 has no data before 2015. There are a few such funds, do they cause problems, or is it better to delete them and remove them from the dataset? I have a total of 27 different fund data.

3)In addition, I have changed the tickers/names of the hedge funds to numeric ID, is it possible to do dummy encoding, would it be better for performance?

**Sample Dataset:**
[image]

**My Idea and First Try:**
I modeled one example. I used a method like this, I shifted(-1) back the target variable. So each line was shown the class in which the fund was located in the following month.I did it because of this, I want to predict the next month before that month starts. Predict to T+1 from T.But this model gave a very poor result.(%43)

view of this model dataset: 
[image]

Comment: How many hedge funds do you have? The problem you're trying to solve is usually called time series classification.

Comment: Hi @mloning, I changed all my modeling procedure and I complete the project with regression models. I was trying to rating hedge funds with machine learning. However, I have done it. I can rating them :)